# Ionic: how to fix UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

when i trying to bulid in ionic app, that shows an error

```
Preparing Firebase on Android
```

(node:11588) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (reje
ction id: 1): [object Object]

(node:11588) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depr
ecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate th
e Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: It’s really hard to answer a question about a bug in code when the question doesn’t include any of the buggy code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).